# Where can I find the modern proof of the prime number theorem?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Terence Tao described a modern proof of the prime number theorem in a lecture in UCLA, which is stated in wiki [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem).

> From wiki: In a lecture on prime numbers for a general audience, Fields medalist Terence Tao described one approach to proving the prime number theorem in poetic terms: listening to the "music" of the primes. We start with a "sound wave" that is "noisy" at the prime numbers and silent at other numbers; this is the von Mangoldt function. Then we analyze its notes or frequencies by subjecting it to a process akin to Fourier transform; this is the Mellin transform. Then we prove, and this is the hard part, that certain "notes" cannot occur in this music. This exclusion of certain notes leads to the statement of the prime number theorem. According to Tao, this proof yields much deeper insights into the distribution of the primes than the "elementary" proofs discussed below.

I wonder where can I find the proof? Anyone give me a reference?

Comment: I think this is referring to, not necessarily [the paper of Riemann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Number_of_Primes_Less_Than_a_Given_Magnitude) but roughly the same but slightly simpler using von mangoldt instead the pi functions and so on..

Comment: The only one I know is the one in Rudin's *Functional Analysis*, Part II. He did it as an application of distribution theory. Although he does not use Mellin transform, he uses Fourier transform and I think it is a 'modern' proof.

Comment: @HuiYu. Thank you. I will read it.

Comment: @spernerslemma. Riemann's paper provides a proof of the prime number theorem?

Answer (score 2):

The outline of this proof was the subject of Riemann's seminal 1859 paper, however it wasn't fully proven until Hadamard and De La Vallee Poussin in 1896.  The prime number theorem is considered to be the pinnacle of 19th century number theory, and Riemmans outline motivated a lot of study in complex analysis.

One of my favorite books on analytic number theory is Montgomery and Vaughn's [Multiplicative Number Theory I: Classical Theory](http://books.google.ca/books/about/Multiplicative_Number_Theory_I.html?id=mrMDWlRZXRsC&redir_esc=y).  Try to see if you can find it in your library.

Chapter 6 deals entirely with the proof of the quantitative prime number theorem, and Chapter 5 provides some background on the Mellin transform, and [Perron's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%27s_formula).  Of particular importance is the quantitative Perron's formula.

Comment: OK. I will look at it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer the proof presented [here](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Prime_Number_Theorem), which is a version of Newman's proof.

Comment: I don't think your proof is valid, look at the final statement in that proof, it doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

There is a complete proof in ["Newman's Short Proof of the Prime Number Theorem"](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.2307/2975232/fulltext.pdf) by Zagier.

Terry Tao's [notes](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2014/12/09/254a-notes-2-complex-analytic-multiplicative-number-theory/) on multiplicative number theory also contain a complete proof of the PNT, including connections to Dirichlet series, the Riemann conjecture, etc.

By the way, both references use a streamlined version of Hadamard's argument that the Riemann's zeta function has not zeros on the line Re(z)=1, an awesome argument...